# contains java- problem

Tags: java

i have this script, and it is suppose  identifier if a player can assist to the suit of a specific card. So, if he assist, show the message, you assist, no problem, but if he does bluff the verification never is done and show the else System.out.println(hand);

the result of this else is [SEVEN of DIAMONDS, FOUR of SPADES, SEVEN of SPADES, KING of DIAMONDS,  more cards]

pn50.getText() (the result of this is CLUBS for example)

my doubt is, what reason the line hand.subList(0, 10).contains(pn50.getText()) never finds nothing in the list (that is the hand of the player)

for example, if the player one plays the king of hearts, and the player two plays the seven of clubs and have the three of hearts in the hand, it is suppose show the message "play another"

```
@Override
    public boolean validCard(List<Card> hand, JTextField pn70, JTextField pn50, int i) {
        if(pn70.getText().equals (pn50.getText())) {
            System.out.println("you assist");
            return true;
        } else {
            if (hand.subList(0, 10).contains(pn50.getText())) {
                System.out.println("play another");
                }
            else 
                System.out.println(hand);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

any help?

thanks

Comment: Also as a side comment, why are only looking to see if the first 11 cards in the hand match?

Comment: it is an example, at the moment i am doing the game with less cards

Comment: The game doesn't matter, I thought the point was the check the whole hand. But here you are only looking at the first 11.

Comment: but i need only check each hand, that have 11 cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to just replace the call to `contains` with a loop:

```
boolean contained = false;
for (Card card : hand.subList(0, 10)) {
  if (card.suit().equals(pn50.getText()) {
    contained = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (contained) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are comparing a String: `pn50.getText()` to a `Card` object. Contains uses the `.equals` method to test equality, unless you set the .equals method on Card to compare to another String, that contains will never return anything.

Here's a solution. I assume you can make Card objects from just strings, so just wrap that string into a Card Object and compare them.

```
Card c = new Card(pn50.getText());
if (hand.subList(0, 10).contains(c)) {
    System.out.println("play another");
}
else 
    System.out.println(hand);
```

Also you would need to override the .equals method on Card to something like:

```
public boolean equals(Card other) {
    return other.getSuit().equals(this.getSuit()) && other.getNumber().equals(this.getNumber());
}
```

Comment: Also note that allowing a `Card` to return `true` from `equals` for a `String` would be a serious violation of the contract of `equals`, since it would not be reflexive (the `String` wouldn't return `true` when given the same `Card`).

Answer (score 0):

Might the problem be that you are comparing object of type *Card* (your List is of this type) to *String* (*JTextField.getText()* returns String) ? :)

*contains*. You may want to override *hashCode()* and *equals()* methods of your *Card* object.

Comment: yes the problem is that, i don't know is how i can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

it is because your source list contains Cards, therefore your sublist contains cards too. `pn50.getText()` returns String that never equals to card.

Comment: thanks, how can I fix this? i need to call method suit(), and if i did if (hand.get(i).suit().subList(5, 10).equals(pn50.getText())) { i receive an error >>>> The method subList(int, int) is undefined for the type String